# Looking for guidelines setting proper ResultSet Type in PreparedStatement API

Tags: performance, jdbc, db2

We recently find using `resultSetType=TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` in `prepareStatement(String sql, int resultSetType, int resultSetConcurrency)` instead of the default `prepareStatement(String sql)` can cause db2 to generate/use a different access plan, which could lead to significantly different query time, depending on table-size/filter range/etc.

We use DB2 LUW V10.5 FP8.

Just wondering if there any guidelines on how to choose this `resultSetType` attribute, in terms of performance optimization, for DB2, or other RDBMS in general? Btw, we don't change our `ResultSet`, so using `*INSENSITIVE` is allowed for us.

Comment: Insensitive doesn't have to do with 'change our ResultSet' (that is what `CONCUR_UPDATABLE` is for), it means the result set isn't updated with concurrent changes (that are visible to the transaction). In any case, if you don't need scrolling, then `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` should be your default in JDBC. This comment is purely from a JDBC perspective, not DB2 specific.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Sounds like from jdbc's perspective, `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` vs. `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` only specifies functionality, and doesn't, or at least not intend to, have any performance implications? it makes to me, since implementations are vendor specific, which brings in all the subtle details, like the one Charles mentioned......

Comment: Performance depends on implementation, eg some drivers implement (simulate) scrollability by caching the while result set in memory.

Answer (score 0):

`TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`

Should be used with care, default is ASENSITIVE.  Which allows Db2 to create either an INSENSITIVE or SENSITIVE cursor depending on what it thinks is best.

With Db2 for i at least, INSENSITIVE causes the DB to create a copy of the data.

Comment: Thanks Charles, that's a very good point, which i didn't think of. 

For our specific query (simple SELECT from a single table....), query time using `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` could be way shorter, and `timeron` is 200 (using `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`) vs. 20,000 (using `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`)..... 

Will try a bunch more similar queries and see what happens. Totally possible we just hit a special case (aka. bug?) ......

Comment: There is no such thing as `ASENSITIVE` in JDBC.